# MT2002: Failed to resolve assembly: System.Web

Tags: ios, xamarin.ios, system.web

I had tracked third party assemblies but not got any clue.This is the error=> Compiling to native code

/Developer/MonoTouch/usr/bin/mtouch -sdkroot "/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer" -v --cache "/Users/volgainfotech/Projects/ScrapBoom/Kiln/Scrapboom-Mongo-Stable/ScrapboomPhone/Scrapboom.iPhone/obj/Debug/mtouch-cache" --nomanifest --nosign -dev "/Users/volgainfotech/Projects/ScrapBoom/Kiln/Scrapboom-Mongo-Stable/ScrapboomPhone/Scrapboom.iPhone/bin/iPhone/Debug/ScrapboomiPhone.app" -r "/Users/volgainfotech/Projects/ScrapBoom/Kiln/Scrapboom-Mongo-Stable/ScrapboomPhone/Scrapboom.Core/bin/iPhone/Debug/ScrapboomCore.dll" -r "/Developer/MonoTouch/usr/lib/mono/2.1/System.dll" -r "/Developer/MonoTouch/usr/lib/mono/2.1/System.Xml.dll" -r "/Developer/MonoTouch/usr/lib/mono/2.1/System.Core.dll" -r "/Developer/MonoTouch/usr/lib/mono/2.1/monotouch.dll" -r "/Developer/MonoTouch/usr/lib/mono/2.1/MonoTouch.Dialog-1.dll" -r "/Users/volgainfotech/Projects/ScrapBoom/Kiln/Scrapboom-Mongo-Stable/ScrapboomPhone/Assets/Emgu.CV.MonoTouch.dll" -r "/Users/volgainfotech/Projects/ScrapBoom/Kiln/Scrapboom-Mongo-Stable/ScrapboomPhone/Assets/Emgu.Util.MonoTouch.dll" -r "/Users/volgainfotech/Projects/ScrapBoom/Kiln/Scrapboom-Mongo-Stable/ScrapboomPhone/Assets/FlurryAnalytics.dll" -debug -profiling -linksdkonly -sdk "6.1" -targetver "3.1" --sgen --abi=armv7 "--linkskip=system.web" "/Users/volgainfotech/Projects/ScrapBoom/Kiln/Scrapboom-Mongo-Stable/ScrapboomPhone/Scrapboom.iPhone/bin/iPhone/Debug/ScrapboomiPhone.exe"
MonoTouch Business version 6.4.1 using framework: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS6.1.sdk
Linking SDK only for assembly /Users/volgainfotech/Projects/ScrapBoom/Kiln/Scrapboom-Mongo-Stable/ScrapboomPhone/Scrapboom.iPhone/bin/iPhone/Debug/ScrapboomiPhone.exe into /Users/volgainfotech/Projects/ScrapBoom/Kiln/Scrapboom-Mongo-Stable/ScrapboomPhone/Scrapboom.iPhone/obj/Debug/mtouch-cache/PreBuild
error MT2002: Failed to resolve assembly: 'System.Web, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'

Answer (score 4):

That error can only occur at **build** time, not when **running** an application.

It means that one of your dependencies (e.g. a 3rd party binary assembly) has a reference to `System.Web.dll`. That assembly is not shipped with (any version of) Xamarin.iOS.

The error does not occur on the simulator because:

- it's, by default, not using the linker (which resolves everything);
- it's using the Just-In-Time (JIT) compiler so it will hit a missing assembly (or member) only when it try execute the code that requires it;
- the Ahead-Of-Time (AOT) compiler, required for running on devices, needs to pre-compile everything, i.e. anything missing will be detected at build time (not runtime)

Comment: So,any solution for it?

Comment: Track your solution dependency on `System.Web` and either update it (with a Xamarin.iOS compatible version) or rebuild it, form source, against the assemblies that are shipped with Xamarin.iOS

Comment: I had tracked third party assemblies but not got any clue.